# Clearing classes from elements in anchor targets

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

All. I have been working on this for some time and can't seem to come up with a solution. I am working on a new FAQ for our intranet and I am using the jquery scrollTo plugin and the localScroll pluging to accomplish the feel of it. One thing I added was when a user clicks the link for the question, it scrolls the user down to the answer and highlights the fieldset in red to indicate the answer to their question.

My JS looks something like this:

```js
function styleRow(myId) {
  ID = myId.substring(1) var ID = document.getElementById(ID)
  ID.className += " highlight"
}
```

My HTML looks like this:

```html
<li><a href="#1_1" onclick="styleRow('#1_1')">Question 1<a></li>
<li><a href="#1_2" onclick="styleRow('#1_2')">Question 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#1_3" onclick="styleRow('#1_3')">Question 3</a></li>


<fieldset class="pad18" id="1_1">
<legend class="SubTitleSmall" id="1_1">Answer 1</legend>
     <p class="MT12 ML24">Answer 1 Text</a></p>
</fieldset> 

     <fieldset class="pad18" id="1_2">
<legend class="SubTitleSmall" id="1_2">Answer 2</legend>
<p class="MT12 ML24">Answer 2 Text</p>
</fieldset> 

<fieldset class="pad18" id="1_3">
<legend class="SubTitleSmall" id="1_3">Answer 3</legend>
     <p class="MT12 ML24">Answer 3 Text</p>
</fieldset>
```

Currently, when a user click a bookmark link the row highlights just fine. However, if they got back to the top and click another link, the styles aren't clearing on the previously selected question. I know there is no code currently included for that, and that is why I am here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A `fieldset` is an element used in `form`s, to identify related `input` elements. For this, I'd suggest using simple `div` elements with a heading.

Comment: Your syntax is weird. You should use `var ID=document.getElementById(myId.substring(1))` instead of `ID = myId.substring(1) var ID = document.getElementById(ID)`. And you should end statements with `;` or, if not, write only one statement on each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use jQuery,

```
function styleRow(myId){
    $(".highlight").removeClass("highlight");
    $(myId).addClass("highlight");
}
```

But be aware that the `id`:

- Must begin with a letter: A-Z or a-z
- Can be followed by letters (A-Za-z), digits (0-9), hyphens ("-"), and underscores ("_")

Comment: This worked great. I am new to JQuery so I am just starting to understasnd syntax. I also work in a very outdated, messy intranet environment. Regardless, this was a great answer. Any tips on where to start with JQuery? Resources?

Comment: @Bearasaurass For me the best way of learning jQuery is answering stackoverflow questions :) (when I started I had never used it, but here everybody who asks a javascript question uses it, so I have been getting used to it). But first of all, I think you need a good plain JavaScript basis, and then you can read http://docs.jquery.com/ -unlike w3c docs, jQuery docs are very good-.

Comment: Even though the above doesn't reflect it, I'm not bad at JavaScript. I use it everyday at work and im constantly becoming more efficient. I appreciate your help.